# Jquery pass different id values to a generic function containing variables

Tags: php, jquery

First timer here, first try at php/jquery

this code is working:

```
$('#update1').click(function(){
    var name= $('#bandname-1').val();
    var bandid = $('#bid-1').val();
    var mbid = $('#mbid-1').val();
    $('#msg').text('updating...');
    $.post('func/update_bandname.php',{
        name: name,
        bandid: bandid,
        mbid: mbid
    }, function(data){
        $('#msg1').text(data);
    });
});
```

this is my php:
-snip

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"bandname-".$i."\" id=\"bandname-".$i."\" value=\"".$name ."\"/>&nbsp;";
echo "<input id=\"update".$i."\" type=\"button\" name=\"update".$i."\" value=\"update\" class=\"dp\"/>";
echo "<span id=\"msg".$i."\"></span><input type=hidden id=\"bid-".$i."\" value=\"".$_REQUEST[bid] ."\" name=bid-".$i."\" />";
echo "<input type=hidden id=\"mbid-".$i."\" value=\"".$bandid."\" name=mbid-".$i."\" />";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
```

the DB returs alot of records into this table, and i created 5 functions update1,update2,etc

is there a way to modify my jquery to pass different id values to one function? instead of copying the function over and over again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a common class and `data-` attribute to each element:

PHP:

```
echo '<input class="updatebutton dp" data-idnum="'.$i.'" id="update'.$i.'" type="button" name="update'.$i.'" value="update">';
```

JS:

```
$('.updatebutton').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).data('idnum'),
       name= $('#bandname-'+id).val(),
       bandid = $('#bid-'+id).val(),
       mbid = $('#mbid-'+id).val();
   $('#msg').text('updating...');
   $.post('func/update_bandname.php', {
            name: name,
            bandid: bandid  ,
            mbid:mbid
   }, function(data) {
            $('#msg'+id).text(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('input[id^=update]').click(function() {
   var id = this.id.match(/\d+/g).join('');
   var name= $('#bandname-'+id).val();
   var bandid = $('#bid-'+id).val();
   var mbid = $('#mbid-'+id).val();
   $('#msg').text('updating...');
   $.post('func/update_bandname.php', {
            name: name,
            bandid: bandid  ,
            mbid:mbid
   }, function(data) {
            $('#msg'+id).text(data);
   });
});
```

But it would be better to use classes instead of IDs.

```
$('.update').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var name = $this.siblings('.bandname').val();
   var bandid = $this.siblings('.bid').val();
   var mbid = $this.siblings('.mbid').val();
   $('#msg').text('updating...');
   $.post('func/update_bandname.php', {
            name: name,
            bandid: bandid  ,
            mbid:mbid
   }, function(data) {
            $this.siblings('.msg').text(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(data) {
    $.post('func/update_bandname.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
       $('#msg1').text(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<form>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"bandname-".$i."\" id=\"bandname-".$i."\" value=\"".$name ."\"/>&nbsp;";
echo "<input id=\"update".$i."\" type=\"button\" name=\"update".$i."\" value=\"update\" class=\"dp\"/>";
echo "<span id=\"msg".$i."\"></span><input type=hidden id=\"bid-".$i."\" value=\"".$_REQUEST[bid] ."\" name=bid-".$i."\" />";
echo "<input type=hidden id=\"mbid-".$i."\" value=\"".$bandid."\" name=mbid-".$i."\" />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
```